# How to display different widgets on specific pages, hide from other pages

Tags: php, sidebar

I want to display a dynamic sidebar on all pages, and a different sidebar on the homepage. There are also particular pages where I don't want to display either of them.

This code is not hiding the unwanted sidebar off of the Homepage; both sidebars show. How can I hide 'multipackage' from the homepage and only display 'singlepackage'? (I guess I thought that the elseif would take care of that. I have also tried just 'else' but I get a syntax error).

```
<?php
    if(!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') 
        || !dynamic_sidebar('multipackage'));

    elseif (is_page_template('page-homepage.php')) {
        dynamic_sidebar('singlepackage');

        // also need to hide both sidebars from Page IDs 4 and 5

        }

    ?>
```

FWIW I have read up on the codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar
, this site, and other resources such as http://dreamwhisperdesigns.com/genesis-tutorials/load-sidebar-specific-pages/ (I am not an experienced php developer and syntax is where I often fail, if that's not already obvious!)

I would really like to avoid using a plugin for this. Thanks everyone in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to display a dynamic sidebar on all pages, and a different sidebar on the homepage. There are also particular pages where I don't want to display either of them.
>
> This code is not hiding the unwanted sidebar off of the Homepage; both sidebars show. How can I hide 'multipackage' from the homepage and only display 'singlepackage'? (I guess I thought that the elseif would take care of that. I have also tried just 'else' but I get a syntax error).

Assuming these conditions:

- `singlepackage` sidebar displays on the **Site Front Page** (or do you mean the **Blog Posts Index**?)
- `multipackage` sidebar displays on **static pages**
- `multipackage` sidebar *does not display* on **static page with ID `$id`**

This is the basic implementation:

```
<?php
if ( is_front_page() ) {
    // This is the Site Front Page,
    // display singlepackage
    dynamic_sidebar( 'singlepackage' );
} else if ( is_page() && ! is_page( $id ) ) {
    // This is a static page,
    // but NOT static page with ID $id;
    // display multipackage
    dynamic_sidebar( 'multipackage' );
}
?>
```

Note: if you want `singlepackage` to display when on the **Blog Posts Index** as opposed to on the **Site Front Page**, you'll want to use `is_home()`:

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) {
    // This is the Site Front Page,
    // display singlepackage
    dynamic_sidebar( 'singlepackage' );
} else if ( is_page() && ! is_page( $id ) ) {
    // This is a static page,
    // but NOT static page with ID $id;
    // display multipackage
    dynamic_sidebar( 'multipackage' );
}
?>
```

If you want to display default content (i.e. content that displays if no Widgets are applied to the specified widget area), then you'll need to use the `if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'singlepackage' ) )`, like so:

```
<?php
if ( is_front_page() ) {
    // This is the Blog Posts Index,
    // display singlepackage
    if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'singlepackage' ) ) {
        // default content goes here
    }
} else if ( is_page() && ! is_page( $id ) ) {
    // This is a static page,
    // but NOT static page with ID $id;
    // display multipackage
    if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'multipackage' ) ) {
        // default content goes here
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is starting to come together in my brain!!!

Comment: The way I have to think of things: figure out the logic in *human terms* (I want X to happen if Y *but not* Z, etc.), and *then* translate those human terms into code. :)

Answer (score 0):

What your code says in English is this:

If there is no dynamic_sidebar function OR there is no sidebar called multipackage ELSE IF this is the home page template THEN show the singlepackage sidebar.

... so you can see that there is no "THEN" part of the first condition.

```
<?php
if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('singlepackage') && is_page_template('page-homepage.php')) {
    dynamic_sidebar('singlepackage');
elseif( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('multipackage'));
    dynamic_sidebar('multipackage');
}
?>
```

This is saying IF the function dynamic_sidebar exists AND there is a singlepackage sidebar AND this is the home page template THEN show the singlepackage sidebar. ELSE IF the function dynmaic_sidebar exists AND there is a multipackage sidebar THEN show the multipackage sidebar.

Comment: You can simplify things significantly by getting rid of the `function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' )` conditional. The `dynamic_sidebar()` function has existed since WordPress 2.9 (or was it 2.8?). **EDIT** Whoops. Make that **[WordPress 2.2](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar#Changelog)**

Comment: True. I didn't optimize this at all, @cindyg. But hopefully seeing this written out this you'll be able to understand it more. Feel free to remove both instances of `function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' )`.

Comment: @developdaly thank you - that makes great sense to me. But when I try it, I get an error on the elseif line. I tried messing around with it but just messed it up more. Like I said my sytax skills are lacking so it's hard for me to figure these things out.

Comment: @Chip Bennett - thanks for the info. I'm a little confused why the codex page for dynamic_sidebar() does not mention that it's deprecated.

Comment: The Codex doesn't mention that `dynamic_sidebar()` is deprecated because **`dynamic_sidebar()` *isn't* deprecated**. :)

Comment: Oh, sorry I misunderstood you.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately none of the help here worked for my particular situation for one reason or another (was running into a lot of syntax errors and I don't know why). This is what ended up working:

```
<?php 
        if ( is_front_page() ) {
            dynamic_sidebar( 'singlepackage' );
        }
        elseif ( is_page(array('827','828','829','830') )) {    
            dynamic_sidebar('multipackage');
        } 
        else {
        }
    ?>
```

which I sort of pieced together from the examples under "Variable Sidebar Content" on - http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: I'm quite happy that you got it working, but this is, in essence, the *exact answer* I gave you. :)

Comment: ahhh, sorry @ChipBennett - that code really had my head spinning. Thank you again for your help, I finally marked your answer :)